# C# DefaultModelBinder does not bind property of type "dynamic"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, model, defaultmodelbinder

I have been trying to figure this one out for the past 2 days...
My main model contains a property of type "dynamic" and looks like this:

```
public class WGTTestModel
{
    private dynamic _oProp3 = null;

    public WGTTestModel()
    {
    }

    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
    private string Prop2 = null;

    public dynamic Prop3
    {
        get
        {
            if (_oProp3 == null)
            {
                // depending on other factors, this could return a different model
                _oProp3 = new SubModel1();
            }

            return _oProp3 ;
        }
        set
        {
            _oProp3 = value;
        }
    }
}
```

SubModel1 looks like this:

```
public class SubModel1
{
    public SubModel1()
    {
    }

    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

The property "WGTTestModel.Prop3" is passed through to a partial view like so:

```
@Html.Partial("~/MVCFrontEnd/Widgets/TESTING/Views/_PartialView.cshtml", (object)Model.Prop3)
```

Note that I had to add the cast to (object) as it was not allowing me to pass along a "dynamic" type.

**Problem: Values that I set on properties "SubModel1.Prop1" & "SubModel1.Prop2" in my partial view do not bind when posting the form.**

The other test I made is by changing the type of "Prop3" from "dynamic" to "SubModel1" in my "WGTTestModel". I was then able to remove the cast to object when passing the model over to the partial view. This time everything works as expected and values bind correctly.

**Is the DefaultModelBinder unable to bind "dynamic" type properties? If so, is there any possible workaround?**

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: No. How would the `DefaultModelBinder` know what model instance to initiate.

Comment: Can I implement a custom model binder to initiate that model? If so, how? I have tried overriding bindModel & getProperties with no luck.

Comment: Only if you were to pass an additional property indicating what model to initialize. But you code can never work anyway. You cannot use a partial to generate form controls for a complex property without also passing the `HtmlFieldPrefix`, and you cannot bind to `object` anyway